# Facebook SDK/Android, Eclipse cannot find resource files

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

When trying to build project HelloFacebookSampleActivity in Eclipse, the layout/main.xml has error

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'confirm_logout' in package 'com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook'

The offending line is

> facebook:confirm_logout="false".

The facebook:confirm_logout is defined in the FacebookSDK project, not in this project.

Comment: Check out the same question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904559/an-issue-with-facebook-sdk-for-android-sample-projects

Comment: Did. I am seeking additional clarification because I've done what I could to make Eclipse aware of the path to the Facebook SDK project. Is the correction to the build path an available option under Build_Path->Configure_Build_Path, or is there a file to edit?

Comment: Found it. For those that also have this problem: in the properties of the project, Properties->Android, select "Add" in the library subpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Build Path properly and make sure you check the Facbook SDK Project as a Library project.These errors are generally due to misconfiguration in Build Paths.

Clean and Build again after your sure of the above.

> Try going to Project > Clean all projects > OK and see if that helps.If you go to the "Problems" tab and paste the different errors you're having it might provide us with more context to help you.

Comment: The three errors are as pasted in the question. The "facebook:" prefix is not being resolved. In Build_Path panel, Facebook SDK is a dependent project, and a library has been created containing the facebooksdk.jar. Are the "facebook:" tags (from FacebookSDK/res/values/attrs.xml) in the jar? Thanks everyone.